# Docker registry image won't start - "exec format error"

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run docker registry on a Raspberry Pi:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:30:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:30:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
 Experimental: false
```

It was installed via `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`, as recommended here https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/

When I run `docker run -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2`, it tries to start but then fails with the error `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that image on a Raspberry Pi, since that image are designed for a `x86_64` architecture. RPi architecture (ARM) is different from PC architecture (x86_64). That implies that Docker images designed for `x86_64` architecture are not compatible with `ARM` architecture. So, you have to use images designed for ARM architecture.

At present there are no strictly official images but the Docker team maintains a number of experimental images under the prefix `arm32v6`.

You should create your own `Registry` image for RPi or use one of the ones available in DockerHub.

This one is a port of the `Registry` official image prepared to run on a RPi: https://hub.docker.com/r/nimblestratus/rpi-docker-registry/

Hope this helps, good luck!